# Rails Routes: Namespace with Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, namespaces

I have a resource that is namespaced inside `api`:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  resources :thing
end
```

(result: `/api/thing/:id`)

I want to have another variable in the url for a non-resource id variable:

`/api/non_resource/:non_resource_id/thing/:id`

How can I add the `:non_resource_id` variable (and associated `non_resource/` section of the url) to the namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scope`:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do

  scope '/non_resource/:non_resource_id' do
    resources :thing
    # other resources
  end

end
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot more! I ran into scope while searching for an answer, but none of the examples or descriptions listed the ability to handle variables in the path. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer, it turns out, is to add a custom path prefix to the resource inside the namespace, not the namespace itself:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  resources :thing, path: '/non_resource/:non_resource_id/things'
end
```

This prefixes all occurrences of that resources urls with the string (including the `things` at the end, because this overrides the defaults which would just be `/things`) and allows access to the `:non_resource_id` variables via the `params` variable in the `thing` controller.